# button share url twitter not run on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, twitter

Why the button not run from mobile?

http://jsfiddle.net/mattisbmx/60p3fdcd/

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="url" data-    text="blablabla" data-via="nn" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the widgets.js to javascript